# How exactly does Cmd-shift-4+space work?

Tags: macos

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>   behaves unexpectedly. For example, when I right-click on Chrome, the captured window does not include the right-click UI.

What exactly determines a unit in  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>   ?

How exactly does  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>    work?

---

(Mac v10.12.5 here, though focused on generality.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## WindowServer

The unit being captured is a layer or window as determined by macOS's [WindowServer process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager).

As a developer, this is accessed through CoreGraphic's [`CGWindowListCreateImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454852-cgwindowlistcreateimage?language=objc) method:

```
CGImageRef CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect screenBounds, CGWindowListOption listOption, CGWindowID windowID, CGWindowImageOption imageOption);
```

This call returns a composite image based on a dynamically generated list of windows.

### Screen Captures with Layers

Tools like [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/), [ScreenShot PSD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screenshot-psd/id489880259?mt=12), and [Ondesoft ScreenCapture](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40592/ondesoft-screencapture) can take screenshots capturing all the individual layers or windows. The resulting capture retains the layering, allowing you to select, hide, or edit windows as desired.

Comment: Wow you mean the resulting capture can allow you to generate a png of any of all combinations of  the layers? Internally does Mac OS uses the same functions as these 3rdparty tools?

Comment: Yes, I use Acorn to capture everything and edit afterwards; you can even move windows around.

Comment: I see it doesn't work for canvas eg Gmail rightclick. Is there any way to "connect" them together?

Comment: Web views are not windows, so macOS does not "see" them. That becomes the responsibility of the browser. Consider [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) explaining what you want to achieve and hopefully someone will know a tool or approach that works for web content.

Comment: For web pages, maybe [PageLayers](https://www.pagelayers.com) does what you want?